# Which is faster, separate conditionals, or combined with elsif?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, is there any difference between pseudocode like:

```
if n > 2:
   do something to A
end

if n > 4:
   do something to B
end

if n >25:
   do something to C
end
```

vs

```
if n>2 && n <4:
  do something to A
elif n >4 && n < 25:
  do something to A and do something to B
elif n > 25:
  do something to A and B and C
end
```

As you can see they do the same thing, but one is easier to read and write if you have a lot of the `if then` statements. However if the multiple `if` blocks are taking up more processing power then it would not be worth it to write it that way.

Therefore I'm wondering if there is a difference between the two? Conceptual answer is fine, I don't need to benchmark anything

Comment: I tried to rewrite your title a bit in hopes of preventing this question from being closed.  I removed the sentence fragment and tried to make it sound more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ they are not equivalent.

The first statement is equivalent to

```
if n>2 && n <= 4:
  do something to A
elif n > 4 && n <= 25:
  do something to A
  do something to B
elif n > 25:
  do something to A
  do something to B
  do something to C
end
```

If `do something to A` returns `nil` or `false`, your second statement won't execute `do something to B`.

And you forgot to handle corner cases like `n = 4` and `n = 25`.

2/ In 99.9% of the case, you should choose the version that is easier to read/understand/debug. Unless this code is running 1000000 times/second, this won't matter.
As you can see, you already created 2 potential bugs by trying to optimizing it prematurely :)

3/ In term of performances, the short answer is: it depends on your data.

The long answer is: You have to try to predict in what range `n` will be in most of the cases.
You can just count the number of comparisons:

`n < 2`: Statement 1: 3 comparisons - Statement 2: 3 comparisons

`2 < n <= 4`: Statement 1: 3 comparisons - Statement 2: 2 comparisons

`4 < n <= 25`: Statement 1: 3 comparisons - Statement 2: 4 comparisons

`25 < n`: Statement 1: 3 comparisons - Statement 2: 5 comparisons

Comment: I made a ton of errors because I was writing it quickly and just wondering out loud but you certainly cleared some of the questions I had. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no difference. Both programs will return a syntax error, and will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't predict a "most common path" (for example, knowing that n is between 2 and 4 the vast majority of the time), I would doubt that the second approach would be any more efficient; the number of comparisons made will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first choice reduces the possibility of logic errors. In the second choice, what happens if `n == 4` or `n == 25`?  Yes, you can fix that easily, but you'd have to recognize the possibility.

I assume the "do something" pseudocode blocks are just method calls, so you don't repeat your text much. It's a hard question to answer because neither method involves nested if-else clauses.  The if clauses are so marginal in cost difference that I would not consider that, and the repetition in "do something" blocks are the same way.  I can imagine a clearer way, however.  Could A, B, and C all have a method like A.handle(n), B.handle(n), and C.handle(n), where the first does nothing if n <= 2, the second does nothing if n <= 4, and the third does nothing if n <= 25?